# How to make the hovered image on top of other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to `hover` images and enlarge the image and image info. I want the hovered images `div` on top of other image `div` instead of covered by other images `div` 
I used `z-index` but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone got a good idears? Thanks a lot.

```
<div class='imgDiv'>
    <img src='a.jpg' />
    <p>hahaha</p>
</div>

<div class='imgDiv'>
    <img src='b.jpg' />
    <p>hahaha</p>
</div>

<div class='imgDiv'>
    <img src='c.jpg' />
    <p>hahaha</p>
</div>

<div class='imgDiv'>
    <img src='d.jpg' />
    <p>hahaha</p>
</div>

......
.....I have so many images divs....
```

CSS

```
.imgDiv{
float:left;
}

.imgDiv:hover{

//part of the enlarge div will be covered by other image divs...
-webkit-transform:scale(1.45, 1.45);
-moz-transform:scale(1.45, 1.45);
-o-transform:scale(1.45, 1.45);
-ms-transform:scale(1.45, 1.45);
transform:scale(1.45, 1.45)


}
```

Jquery

```
$('.imgDiv').hover(function(){

  //not working...
  $(this).css('z-index','999');       

})
```

Comment: not working in all browsers or just IE ?

Comment: This works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox. It doesn't work in IE7 for me. Can you create an example on JSFiddle showing where it is does not work or give us a link to a live example? Could be some other styles on the page that is causing the issue.

Comment: @sarcastyx sure...i will do it tomorrow at work

Answer (score 1):

For the `z-index` to work, `position` must be `absolute`. You will probably have to toggle absolute positionning on hover, and set the `top` and `left` attributes so the div stay in place.

It will be easier if you're not having your divs floating.

Remember that absolute position is relative to the *first positionned element*. Not necessarily the body element. It is relative to the first parent that has its `position` set to something.

**edit**
As @ahren pointed out in his comment, I was wrong with `z-index` only workin with `position: absolute;`.

That said, I setted up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5E7e/2/) with your code except the javascript part, and it seems to work as expected. The behavior is the same with chrome / firefox / ie9.  Maybe other parts of your html/css is causing the issue? Or I misunderstood the question?

Comment: FYI; `z-index` works with any position other than `static`. The element could be positioned `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: Thanks ahren for the precision. I didnt situation where a z-index is applicable to, say, a relative position, but thinking of it you're right.